# tfs merged changeset still appears in merge wizard when from trunk to branch

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, changeset

We have an issue where changesets that have already been merged between 2 branches appear in the list when merging the opposite direction.  I have blogged it but don't see a fix except way back in TFS 2010.  We are on TFS 2013 Upgrade 5.

Example:

- We have a trunk with a Dev branch.
- Do some work in DEv, checkin changeset 1, merge to Trunk.
- Now Trunk and Dev are in sync.
- Now use the wizard to merge from Trunk down to dev.  changeset 1 appears in the list when it shouldn't.  The two branches are identical.

The scenario when you would need to do this are simply that changes were merged to Trunk from another branch or directly to trunk for a bug fix for example.  Then you need to merge down from Trunk to Dev to get dev in sync with some changes that are necessary in Dev branch.

This used to work and it broke at some point in the 2008 or 2010 version.  We are on 2013 and still an issue.

Can anybody tell me if this has been addressed?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this fixable with `tf merge /discard /baseless`?

Comment: Per my experience, there is no way to have changeset1 shown up when merge from Trunk to Dev branch. Please have a double check to be sure that you don't mix up changeset1 with other changeset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on my machine. My TFS2013 Update 5 works correctly.

Please be sure that

1). The merged changeset1 is checked in to the Trunk branch.

2). When merge from Trunk to Dev branch, please select the **Selected changesets** option on the **Source Control Merge Wizard** dialog. 
[image]

If there is no changeset to merge, the **No changes are eligible to merge from the source to the target** message will shown. If you still have this issue, please clean local workspace cache to see whether it helps: empty the folder C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

Comment: The problem appears to be resolved.  While researching this, 2 things occurred.  We created a new development branch as we are in a new phase of the project.  Secondly, I cleared the cache as recommended above.   So I'm not sure which one fixed it but I'm going to assume it was cache.  Thanks!